# MD5 password sent to a mysql field of INT

Tags: mysql, int, md5, field

I was sending an encrypted password (in md5) to a sql database. Accidentally, i sent an md5 encryption to an integer column. The password I entered was "test" and in my database it showed up as "5" then I did a password of "qwertyqwerty" and it showed up as "2147483647" Out of curiosity, can anyone explain to me what's going on with this? Why are the int values so much different?

Comment: 2147483647 is the maximum value of a SIGNED INT column.

Comment: Why would you use md5 for password hashing? PBKDF2 or bcrypt are the standard choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 does not encrypt a password, it hashes it.

A hash is a one-way function that takes a given input and creates a predictable output (that is, a given input will always have the same output), ideally such that even very similar inputs will yield vastly different outputs.

MD5 hashes are 128 bits.  If you try to write those 128 bits into a 32 bit SQL column, some truncation will certainly happen.

Without understanding the specific code you used to generate the MD5, convert it to an integer, and then write it to SQL, it's not possible to understand why in one case you got a small number, and in another you got the maximum value for a signed int.  If you wish to post the code, I'm glad to comment on it.

Comment: it was unintentional and ive fixed the problem since then (i want it in md5, doesnt need true encryption), but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why the first value showed up as 5 (I'd have to see the hash), but your second value showed up as what it did because that's the max value an integer column can hold.

When mysql converted your string MD5 hash to an integer (or tried to), it exceeded the max value an integer can hold, so it saved the max integer instead.